# comparing one column from a Dataframe to another of different sizes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have two dataframe one with the job info and another with the person Name and title as below

```
jobTitle = {'Role': ['Level1','Level2','Level3'],
            'Position': ['Manager','Engineer','Assistant']
            'Salary': [1,2,3]
               }
```

```
job_df = pd.DataFrame(jobTitle,columns=['Role','Position','Salary'])
person = {'Name':['John','Shawn'],
         'Level1':['Level2','Level1'],
         'Position1': ['Engineer','Manager']}
person_df = pd.DataFrame(person,columns=['Name','Level1','Position1'])
```

I want to compare each person's role and position with the jobTitle Dataframe and add a new column in person with the salary

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using `pd.DataFrame.merge`:

```
>>> person_df.merge(job_df, left_on=['Level1', 'Position1'], right_on=['Role', 'Position']).drop(job_df.columns[:2], axis=1)
    Name  Level1 Position1  Salary
0   John  Level2  Engineer       2
1  Shawn  Level1   Manager       1
>>>
```